# How to search the entire binary tree for ints under x and write them to txt file in C

Tags: c, search, binary-tree

How to search the entire binary tree for ints under x and write them to txt file in C.
I tried this code but only part of the tree gets searched.

```
void save_tree_to(FILE *out, bst *root, unsigned x)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    save_tree_to(out, root->left, x);
    if (root->price <= x)
    {
        save_item_to(out, root);
    }
    save_tree_to(out, root->right, x);
}

void save_item_to(FILE *out, bst *m)
{
    fprintf(out, "%d\n", m->price);
}
```

Comment: You say, "only part of the tree gets searched ". How do you know that? If you remove the if-condition and just do a hard in-order traversal from the unposted code that produces the unposted tree assumedly rooted at `root`, does every node in the tree print?  Provide a proper [mcve] and we *may* be able to help. Without one, we're literally left to sooth-say and toss wild guesses

Comment: is your question about the "under 5" part or about the "but only part of the tree gets searched"? Actually, what is your question?

Comment: The algo looks fine. Without a [mre] I cannot guess what the problem can be.

Comment: Please show what is actually printed, what you expect to be printed, and what tree you feed as the input. (Think well about how to show the tree. Perhaps info about [mcve] will help.)

Comment: Also ber in mind that if the root is under 5, then the entire left subtree is under 5 too, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to search it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: consider a tree with values 1 2 3 (left-root-right). Searching for 1 immediately returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subtree that has a root `>x` can very well contain elements `≤x`, you terminate the search too early.

Stop the search only when you have reached a *leaf* `>x`.